# Как получить доступ к модели приложения из виджета?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Возникла проблема - У меня есть класс в основном приложении. В виджете я пытаюсь создать временную шкалу из данных модели. Приложение и виджет объединяются в группу, а модель указывается в целевом объекте виджета. Временная шкала создается, но переменная пуста. Что я делаю не так?

```
@Model
final class Trip {
     var datefrom: Date
     var datediff: Int
     init(datefrom: Date = Date(), datediff: Int = 0) {
         self.datefrom = datefrom
         self.datediff = datediff
     }
}
```

в Виджете - переменная daycount всегда пустая ...

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    let trips = [Trip]()
    var entries: [AppEntry] = []
    var daycount = ""
    var dateOfCount = Date.now

    for hourOffset in 0 ..< 10 {
        let dateOfCount = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: hourOffset, to: Date.now)!
        var countDays = 0

        trips.forEach{item in
            if item.datefrom > dateOfCount {
                 countDays = countDays + Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: item.datefrom, to: dateOfCount).day!+1
            }
       }
       daycount = String(countDays) // переменная всегда пустая ...

       let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: hourOffset, to: Date.now)!
       let entry = AppEntry(date: entryDate, countdays: daycount)
       entries.append(entry)
    }
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```